# How to call back the previous form in Winforms application?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I wants to create one form called Filter. That form will be called by rest of all forms.

**For Example**

> I have 10 forms and one filter form. I have a button called **Filter** in all the 10 forms. so whenever user click the Filter button, the `Filter form` will be called and pass the value

**ReportForm1**

```
//Send Values to Filter Form
private void OnButton1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();
    FilterForm filter = new FilterForm(txtFieldName.Text,txtValues.Text);
    filter.Show();
}

//Get back the values from Filter Form
public ReportForm1(string x, string y)     
{
    s1 = x;
    s2 = y;

    // I will do some process after I get back the values from Filter Form
}
```

**Filter Forms**

```
public filter(string FieldName, string Values)     
{
    s1 = FieldName;
    s2 = Values;

    // I will do some process after I get back the values from Filter Form
}

private void OnSubmitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Hide();

    //it has to send two variables to previous form.
}
```

There are some components I will add in Filter Form like textbox,combobox,list,grid and some of button click functions. Finally when user click **submit button** It should send some values to Previous form.

**Note**

> please don't suggest me to call the form like `ReportForm1 report1=new ReportForm1(x,y)`. I am expecting it has to call the previous form. Because when I ever I create a new form ex. ReportForm2, the function will be still same in `FilterForm`. So I don't want to create object for all the forms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this below solution..

1. Instead of calling `Show()` call `ShowDialog()`.
2. Assign the necessary values to properties (public) in Filter form and access those values in Main form using Filter form's object.

**Main Form:**

```
private void OnButton1Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    FilterForm filter = new FilterForm(txtFieldName.Text,txtValues.Text);
    if (filter.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        TextBox a = filter.a; //Here you can able to access public property from Filter form.
    }
}
```

**Filter Form:**

```
public class FilterFom
{
    public TextBox a { get; private set; }

    public filter(string FieldName, string Values)     
    {
        s1 = FieldName;
        s2 = Values;
        a = new TextBox(); //Here I can assign value to public property of this class.
    }

    private void OnSubmitClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have one doubt `if (filter.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)`. will it perform like a dialog box?. If yes, can i add components like textbox,grid control,listbox and 4 button click events?